# Estmation of Spatial autoregressive parameter

Tags: generalized-linear-model, estimation, maximum-likelihood, linear-model, spatial

Consider the linear model 
$$Y=\rho W Y+ X\beta +\epsilon.$$

where $W$ is the weight matrix, $\rho$ is spatial auto regressive  parameter.

One can see the above model as,

$$(I-\rho W) Y= X\beta +\epsilon.$$

Hereby, using Maximum likelihood estimation, I could find the estimator of $\beta$ as $$\hat\beta=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T(I-\rho W) Y.$$

Using these information, can the $\rho$ be estimated?